# Obtener Lyrics de una canción sin scrap

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando obtener los Lyrics de cualquier canción a partir de su nombre.

He intentado utilizar PyLyrics, pero me obliga (O al menos no he encontrado la forma de evitarlo) a aportar el nombre del Artista.

```
from PyLyrics import *

print(PyLyrics.getLyrics('Taylor Swift','Blank Space')) #Print the lyrics directly
```

En caso de no utilizar uno de los 2 parametros, salta un error.

Otra idea es usar alguna librería que a partir del nombre de la canción me saque el nombre del artista.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la [API de Musicdemons](https://musicdemons.com/api)

Es una API REST y aunque no conozco una librería para python que simplifique el uso, la verdad es que no es nada difícil hacer llamadas directamente desde `requests` por ejemplo.

Por ejemplo, lo siguiente te saca la lista de canciones para la búsqueda "Blank Space".

```
import requests

cancion = "Blank Space"
url = "https://musicdemons.com/api/v1/song/organic-search/"
r = requests.get("{}{}".format(url, cancion))
if r.ok:
  canciones = r.json()
  for cancion in canciones:
    print("{} ({})".format(
        cancion["title"],cancion["released"][:4]))
```

```
Blank Space (2014)
Black Hypocrisy (2018)
```

La búsqueda es "inteligente" como ves (;-P) pues busca también cosas similares. Está ordenada de modo que la primera es la más probable.

Podemos pedir que además de título y fecha nos proporcione las *lyrics*. En el código siguiente imprimo título y letra del primer resultado:

```
cancion = "Blank Space"
url = "https://musicdemons.com/api/v1/song/organic-search/"
r = requests.get("{}{}".format(url, cancion), headers={"with": "lyrics"})
if r.ok:
  canciones = r.json()
  primer_resultado = canciones[0]
  titulo = primer_resultado["title"]
  letra = primer_resultado["lyrics"][0]["lyrics"]
  print(titulo)
  print("==================")
  print(letra)
```

```html
Blank Space
==================
Nice to meet you, where you been?
I could show you incredible things
Magic, madness, heaven, sin
Saw you there, and I thought
"Oh my God, look at that face

[...] Omito, es muy larga

They'll tell you I'm insane
But I've got a blank space, baby
And I'll write your name
```